Laravel Excel custom validation
I am attempting to use a custom validation rule to validate data in an Excel file. The following code is from the Controller: Excel::import(new StudentValidation, $request->file('file'));. The StudentValidation file is as follows:
namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Rules\CheckStudentDetails;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Rules\CheckStudentDetailsExcel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class StudentValidation implements ToModel, WithValidation
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {     
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            new CheckStudentDetailsExcel(
                $rows["first_name"] ?? null,
                $rows["last_name"] ?? null,
                isset($rows['date_of_birth']) ? Date::excelToDateTimeObject((int) $rows['date_of_birth'])->format('Y-m-d') : null,
                $rows["gender"] ?? null,
                $rows["index_number"] ?? null
            )
        ];
    }
}

This is the custom validation rule (CheckStudentDetailsExcel). It checks if the first name, last name, gender, and DoB exist. If true, it throws an error message.
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CheckStudentDetailsExcel implements Rule
{
    protected $fname;
    protected $lname;
    protected $dob;
    protected $gender;
    protected $index;

    public function __construct($fname, $lname, $dob, $gender, $index)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;
        $this->lname = $lname;
        $this->dob = $dob;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->index = $index;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Check if any of the values are null
        if (is_null($this->fname) || is_null($this->lname) || is_null($this->dob) || is_null($this->gender) || is_null($this->index)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Your validation logic here, e.g., checking if the student details already exist in the database
        // Example: return !Student::where('fname', $this->fname)->where('lname', $this->lname)->exists();

        return true; // Replace this with your actual validation logic
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'A student with the given details already exists.';
    }
}


I am expecting a validation like the following:
  $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                "school" => "required",
                // "index" => ["bail", "required", "size:12", "unique:tblstudent,index_no", new CheckStudentIndexNumber($request->status), new CheckStudentSchool($request->school, $request->status)],
                // "index" => ["bail", "nullable", "size:12", "unique:tblstudent,index_no", new CheckStudentIndexNumber($request->status), new CheckStudentSchool($request->school, $request->status)],
                "index" => ["bail", "nullable", "size:12", "unique:tblstudent,index_no"],
                // "index" => ["bail", "nullable", "size:12", "unique:tblstudent,index_no"],
                // "fname" => ["required_if:index",new CheckIfIndexFilled(), new CheckStudentDetails($request->input('fname'), $request->input('lname'), $request->input('dob'), $request->input('gender') )],
                "fname" => ["required", new CheckStudentDetails($request->input('fname'), $request->input('lname'), $request->input('dob'), $request->input('gender'), $request->input('index') ?? null)],
                "lname" => "required",
                // "form"=> "required",
                // "course"=> "required",
                "class_code" => "required",
                 "gender" => "required",
                  "dob" => "required",
                // "admission_date" => "required",
                "admission_date" => "nullable",
                "email" => "nullable|email|unique:tblstudent,email",
                "town" => "required",
                "district" => "nullable",
                "region" => "nullable",
                "guard_fname" => "required",
                "guard_lname" => "required",
                "guard_phone" => "required",
                "guard_gender" => "required",
                "guard_relation" => "required",
                "session" => "required",
                "status" => "required",
            ],
            [
                // This has our own custom error messages for each validation
                // "index.numeric" => "Index Number must be a number",
                "school.required" => "No school supplied",
                "index.required" => "No index number supplied",
                "index.unique" => "Index number supplied already exists in the system",
                "fname.required" => "No fname supplied",
                "lname.required" => "No lname supplied",
                "dob.required" => "No dob supplied",
                "gender.required" => "No gender supplied",
                "town.required" => "No town supplied",
                "district.required" => "No district supplied",
                "admission_date.required" => "No admission date supplied",
                "region.required" => "No region supplied",
                "guard_fname.required" => "No Guardian first name supplied",
                "guard_lname.required" => "No Guardian last name supplied",
                "guard_phone.required" => "No Guardian phone number supplied",
                "guard_gender.required" => "No Guardian gender supplied",
                "session.required" => "No Student Session supplied",
                "index.exists" => "This Index Number does not exist in our records",
                "class_code.required" => "No Student Class selected",
            ]
        );

